# conditional on terminal type (or 'set' variable in general) / read a 'set' variable?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a series of gnuplot scripts which I have developed using the default 'qt' terminal on my OS X system.  This has the convenient feature of closing the closing the qt window when the script completes, so I added:

```
pause mouse "mouse button 2 or 3 to close\n";
```

Later in development I want to output to pdf, but now the pause hangs my command line terminal until I hit return.  I wanted to do:

```
set terminal pdf
...
if (terminal eq qt) pause mouse "mouse button 2 or 3 to close\n";
```

but this gives me:

line 45: undefined variable: terminal

I now have a workaround of setting a different variable and setting the terminal from it:

```
term = 'qt'
if (term eq 'pdf') set terminal pdf ; set output 'rToR.pdf'
...
if (term eq 'qt') pause mouse "mouse button 2 or 3 to close\n";
```

which may be arguably better for some code design aspects, but requires a layer of redundancy and isn't actually what I want to do.

Therefore, is there way to / how do I access the value of a gnuplot setting like 'terminal'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `show variables all` for a list of available variables. In your case you need `GPVAL_TERM`:

```
if (GPVAL_TERM eq 'qt') { ... }

if (GPVAL_TERM eq 'pdfcairo') { ... }
```

With `set terminal pdf` usually, the `pdfcairo` terminal is selected, so you need the string `'pdfcairo'` for the comparison.